# Installed Windows 7, then Ubuntu. Cant boot windows 7, although option appears in GRUB menu?

Tags: grub2, windows-7

Basically installed windows 7, followed by Ubuntu installation. Option to boot windows appears in GRUB menu, but when I select it and hit enter I get redirected back to same GRUB menu? What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Try to use this tool => [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) to resolve your problem. If problem persists then give here the link with boot-info summary.

Comment: Did you install Windows 7, and then do a few re-starts and update for Windows 7? **OR** Did you immediately install **Ubuntu** after installing Windows 7?

Comment: I did it immediately.

Anyway NikTh suggestion fixed it.. Thanks guys! :)